# Sorted Map with non-unique keys

Tags: java, collections

What structure to use when one needs

1. ordering of elements by key
2. ability to hold non-unique keys

   ```
   Structure<Integer, String> struct = new Structure<Integer, String>;
   struct.add(3,"...");
   struct.add(1,"John");
   struct.add(2,"Edwin");
   struct.add(1,"Mary");
   struct.toString() == {key-> value;} [1->"John",1->"Mary",2->"Edwin",3->"..."]
   ```

Answer (score 13):

If you want use the standard Java API, I would choose a `TreeMap<Integer, Set<String>>`.

- The elements are ordered by the keys since it is a `SortedMap`. From the docs:

  > The map is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time. This order is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views (returned by the entrySet, keySet and values methods).
- The structure allows for non-unique keys as you can let one key map to multiple objects.

This type of structure is called a *sorted multi-map* and there are several implementations that hide the details of creating initial sets when inserting for the first time etc. Have a look at [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) for instance.

Depending on your needs, you could also have a `SortedSet<Pair<Integer, String>>`, where the elements are sorted on the left element in the pair. (Note that you would have write the Pair class yourself, but it shouldn't be more than a few lines.)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you need perhaps a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` so each key maps to a list (or other collection) of strings.

Apache Commons has a [MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html), which does the above without the hassle of you coding it.

```
 MultiMap mhm = new MultiHashMap();
 mhm.put(key, "A");
 mhm.put(key, "B");
 mhm.put(key, "C");
 Collection coll = (Collection) mhm.get(key);
```

coll will be a collection containing "A", "B", "C".

Google Collections will provide something similar, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using multimap implementations from Apache Commons or Guava, or implementing a `Pair` class as suggested by other answers, you can simply use a `TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>`. Instead of a key mapping to a single `String`, it now maps to a `List` which can hold multiple values and thus work effectively like a multimap.

But I'd go with a proper multimap for production code though.